# XSL-FO 組版 左綴じ、右綴じ での記述の違い

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo

組版する際に、左綴じ、右綴じ と、閉じる側を意識することがあるかと思いますが、
XSL-FO では、左綴じ、右綴じ で、記述が異なりますか？

- 左綴じ、右綴じで、要素、プロパティ等の違い
- その他、留意点、注意点

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一般に閉じる側ののどはマージンを小口より多めに取ります．従って、各ページマスターにおいて

左綴じでは、@margin-left > @margin-right
右綴じでは、@margin-left < @margin-right

とするのが一般的と思います．

またページマスターのマージンでなく、fo:region-bodyのマージンで調整する方法もあると思います．